# Smart capsules for radioactive metals

Tags: radiation

If we add or remove an election to the atoms of radioactive metals, they will become the isotopes of their adjacent chemical elements in the periodic table. I ask the community whether the resulted isotopes will still emit radiation.

Answer (score 1):

> If we add or remove an election to the atoms of radioactive metals, they will become the isotopes of their adjacent chemical elements in the periodic table.

You don't change isotopes by adding or removing electrons. That is called ionization, except that you really can't ADD electrons. You change isotopes by adding or removing protons or neutrons. The resulting new isotopes may or may not be radioactive.

For instance, adding a proton to $^{60}$Ni (Nickel 60) produces $^{61}$Cu (Copper 61), which is intensely radioactive, while adding a proton to $^{62}$Ni produces $^{63}$Cu, which is stable.

Comment: As a small correction, negative ions are well known and used in accelerators. Some (like the noble gasses) are unstable, many others (such as H$^{-}$, Si$^{-}$, ...) are stable in isolation.